# Detecting "overflow" on HTML dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I detect if there is more text in the selected dropdown ('select') element than is being shown to the user?

I found a way to make this work on inputs of type text (**currently only working for me in Chrome... a cross-browser solution would be great), but am also trying to get it to work on selects:

```
function applyTitles(jqueryElement) {
var element = jqueryElement[0];
if (element.offsetHeight < element.scrollHeight || element.offsetWidth < element.scrollWidth) {
    // element has overflow
    jqueryElement.attr('title', jqueryElement.val());
}
else {
    //element doesn't have overflow
    jqueryElement.attr('title', '');
}}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NML3f/

My goal is to create a generic way of dynamically showing titles on inputs when the entire thing can't be seen at once. For some reason, I thought some browsers did this automatically, but I guess not.

Comment: Since rendering of form elements is largely left to the OS, you'll probably have to roll your own fake select-dropdown in order to achieve this kind of detection.

Comment: Thanks. That's too bad... I will probably end up either ballparking it by the character count, applying the titles to all elements regardless of their content, or just leaving it be and frustrating users a tiny bit.